# How can pixels display brown, while RGB led's lights can't?

Tags: colors, rgb, pixel, monitor

While busy with project I'm wondering how you can't make a brown looking color with a RGB led light, but pixel can display brown really well. What is the biggest different between a RGB led light(for example a MiLight or Arduino RGB LED) and a (monitor) pixel what makes it works?

Is there a way to program any RGB light to output a brown light color?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. There are other sites in the SE network more suitable to give you an answer. You'd also explain what RGB led light are you referring to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

LEDs are rather large so your eye can easily identify only the R and B being on for example, so we see a red and a blue light source. A monitor pixel is so small that our brain sees the R and B as magenta instead.

You can read about [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel#Subpixels).

Comment: So,brown neither exist in pixels? That awesome (and kinda weird at the same time).

Comment: Nope, monitor pixels usually consist of three columns each, red, green then blue. Each column is thus one pixel high and 1/3 pixel wide.

Comment: I found this usefull, it crushed my brains for day while watching any TV, monitor or Mobile phone. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to create a RGB light with many pixels inside the bulb, to make your brain think like it's brown ?

Comment: If you get the LEDs close enough together or have the viewer at a far enough distance that could do the trick but I don't know how you would do it with only regular LEDs.

Comment: I thought a round pixels ring inside a round glass (bulb). But I've no clue how screens which make use of pixels get manufactured :/ I neither know how to prototype with single pixels. Is there any software that provide those functionally? They're so tiny :)

Comment: Edit; I properly know why, the small pixels can't handle the same amount of power. This means 1000 pixel will not output the same brightness as 1 Power RGB LED, while the is relatively equal.

Comment: While the size is relatively equal*

Answer (score 0):

Brown is a very weird colour. It's a colour of context. It doesn't exist otherwise. We perceive dark shades of orange as brown, because we decided to separate them as separate colour. You can only see brown if you can see surrounding area, context, in which that colour is displayed. Monitor can very well control amount of light emitted and also display almost perfect black next to a colour. To see brown, you must display brighter surrounding what is totally possible on monitor. LED can decrease its brightness, but it is emitting light in a way that can't display dimmed orange fragment surrounded by brighter light, hence your brain can't perceive brown in such setup and will always see shades of orange at best.